# Kак открыть консоль из консоли в новом окне? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

В коде есть строка которая открывает другое консольное приложение

system("D:\secondProgram.exe");

как сделать что бы то другое приложение открылось в новом окне?
а что бы программа которая его открыло - закрылась!?!?

Comment: `start second.exe`Ю а свою завершить?

Comment: да свою завершить

Comment: Ну так по окончании работы вашей программы консоль с ней закроется... Или вы ее запускаете в заранее открытой консоли?

Comment: да спасибо проблема решена